# Shopify REST API cannot delete product images

Tags: python, rest, shopify

I have the following custom function in python to communicate with the Shopify REST API via requests to delete images from products,

```
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

def delete_product_image(shop_url, product_id, image_id,headers):
    del_r = requests.delete(f'{shop_url}/products/{product_id}/images/{image_id}.json()',headers=headers)
    if del_r.status_code in [200, 201]:
        print(f'image {image_id} of product {product_id} removed')
    else:
        print(f'Error: {del_r.status_code} - {del_r.text}')
        time.sleep(1)
        delete_product_image(shop_url, product_id, image_id)
```

If I execute the `delete_product_image(shop_url, product_id, image_id,headers)` the `del_r` status code returns `200`, but the images are not deleted from the products.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should just remove the `()` in your URL.

```py
headers = {"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"}

def delete_product_image(shop_url, product_id, image_id,headers):
    del_r = requests.delete(f'{shop_url}/products/{product_id}/images/{image_id}.json',headers=headers)
    if del_r.status_code in [200, 201]:
        print(f'image {image_id} of product {product_id} removed')
    else:
        print(f'Error: {del_r.status_code} - {del_r.text}')
        time.sleep(1)
        delete_product_image(shop_url, product_id, image_id)
```

Maybe it returns 200, because the file (with `()`) does not exist (anymore).